# Many parameters with one name in form and get a list of them in

Tags: html, django, post, methods, dynamic-forms

I have a form with dynamic fields..

When submit form, i have this:

```
   Localhost:8000/mysite.com/jobs_form?job="Job1"&job="Job2"
```

And i cant get all of them in django with request.POST.get("job")

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the [**`.getlist(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) of the [**`request.GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) querydict:

```
request.GET.getlist('job')
```

This will return a list with the two jobs, so `['Job1', 'Job2']`.